# Contentprovider: How to use a reference for it?

Tags: android, service, android-contentprovider

I want to use a Contentprovider within a Service. I've written a handler-class to parse JSON and want to insert data in my contentprovider, how is it possible to give a Service a reference for the contentprovider?

Comment: context.getContentResolver() .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are on the right track, but I feel that they need elaboration:

Content providers, even ones that you only use within your own app, are not designed to be referenced directly. Instead, an app should use methods in ContentResolver to access a content provider. ContentResolver features the same set of methods as those that you **must** implement for ContentProvider (its abstract methods). For example, if you want to insert data into a ContentProvider, you call getContentResolver().insert(). A ContentResolver is a general-purpose object for communicating with content providers, file providers, and the sync adapter framework.

When you define a content provider in your app, you have to define its authority value in the manifest, and you also have to write code that interprets incoming content URIs. The best way to work with content URIs is to start by assigning a separate content URI to each table in your provider, using the form

```
content://*authority*/*path*
```

*Authority* is the authority string you specified in the manifest; the *de facto* standard is to use your app's package name with ".provider" appended to it. *Path* is a descriptive term for the table it represents. For example:

```
content://com.example.android.myapp.provider/sales
```

to point to the Sales table in your provider. You can get fancier if you want, but most developers will satisfy their needs with this proposal.

To work with content URIs in your content provider, use the android.content.UriMatcher class.

Comment: I thought ContentResolver are only used in Activities, but there I use Loaders.
I've tried. Services have a getContentResolver()-Method. 
So you three are right. Thanks!

Comment: ContentResolver can be used from almost anything. A CursorLoader is preferred for queries, but simple queries and other operations don't necessarily need one. getContentResolver() is actually a method of the Context class, so any component class (such as Service) that inherits from android.content.Context will have getContentResolver(). If your object doesn't inherit Context (for example, Fragment), then your object usually has a method that gets an object that *does* inherit (for example, Fragment.getActivity()).

Answer (score 0):

Just call  `getContentResolver()` from your service;